# Menu item not visible in one language

Tags: asp.net, resources, multilingual

Is possible to set in resources that any menu elements will not visible in one of languages?

Best regards,
Dagna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you already know how to use local resources. If not, check this: [ASP.NET Web Page Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

If you use local resources (App_LocalResources), you can refer to pretty much any property of any control in the page linked to the local resources.

So in the page linked to the local resources, if you have a server-side menu element (with the runat="server" tag) and with the id "menuElement", you could set this in your resources file.

"Name" | "Value"

menuElement.Visible | False

For example, you could set the value to False in your French resources file and the value to True in English resources file. The control menuElement would be visible only in English.